# Position a div | nest <form>s

Tags: forms, html, position, nested, floating

I want to nest a form within a form. But of course that is illegal code.
Because of this I want to position this div 

<div id="div_2">

 (which I have coded at the end of my document) into this table cell: 

<td id="place_here"> 

Is this even possible? 
I will drive myself crazy using a relative or absolute position in CSS, trying to get my div perfectly into position in every browser.

That is why I gave that table cell in id.
I'm hoping css or jquery will help me position the div relative to the table cell id="place_here" and NOT the top of the document

```
<form id="CTRP_Form">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="div_1"><input id="fnam" name="fnam" form="CTRP_Form" type=text></div>
</td>
<td id="place_here">
<!-- place div id=2 here -->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


<div id="div_2"><form id="query_Form"><input type=submit></form></div>
```

Comment: That approach sounds a little wonky to me... Why wouldn't you just move the first form into the table-cell like you have the other one?

Answer (score 0):

You you can do it by specifying the margin-top property and using a negative value

```
<div id="div_2" style="margin-top:-160px"></div>
```

Hope this works for you.

OR

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="div_1">
<form id="CTRP_Form">
<input id="fnam" name="fnam" form="CTRP_Form" type=text>
</form>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="div_2"><form id="query_Form"><input type=submit></form></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

OR

For some reason if your first form is too large and its content changes while filling it out(e.g.. some inputs might get hide when certain options are selected).

Here is what you can do. You can place a small empty div in

Then your div 2 will go after your first form.

Then use this javascript to position div_2 relative to parent div.

```
function position_mdiv(){

    var pos=$('#parent').position();
    var width=$('#parent').outerWidth();

    $('#div_2').css({
       position: "absolute",
       top: pos.top + "px",
       left: (pos.left + width) + "px"
    });

}
```

Then put it in document.ready in jquery so when the page loads/window is resized it will adjust its position accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    position_mdiv()();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        position_mdiv();
    });
});
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Nested Forms</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table border="3" width="500" height="400" align="center" style="margin-top:40px">
<tr> 
<td style="background:green">Form1
<input type="text" placeholder="name"/><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td style="background:red" valign="top"><div id="co">form2 place</div></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

<div id="tobepositioned" style="background:yellow;
width:400px;padding:10px;border:solid   2px #CCC">
Form2
<form name="form2">
<input type="text" name="s"/><input type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
position_mdiv();

// running this function on resize too
$(window).resize(function() {
    position_mdiv();
});

});


// function to position the div2

function position_mdiv(){

var pos=$('#co').position();
var width=$('#co').outerWidth();
//alert(pos.left);
$('#tobepositioned').css({
position: "absolute",
top: pos.top + "px",
left: (pos.left) + "px"
});

}


</script>
tested in IE10, Firefox, Chrome
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the first from. There's a lot of form input I did not include.

Comment: If I use an id on that table cell, can I position my exterior div relative to the id number? <br/> 
    <td id="placemarker">
    <!-- place div id=2 here -->
    </td>

Comment: What do you mean? please explain in detail. If you explain properly i might be able to solve your problem quickly.

Comment: Muhammad, I have edited my original question to re-explain more clearly. Your first suggestion could work, but it will drive me crazy trying to get it right for every browser. Your second suggestion will not work. I have inputs for form #1 everywhere on that page. That is why I want to nest a form within a form, if I can do it? That is why I came up with the idea of putting an id in a table cell. Can I position a div relative to that table cell (and not the top of the page)?

Comment: Please check the update on the answer. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I've been playing with it: http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~paradesquare/DPR_Simulator/test_divs.html but I get TypeErrorpos is undefined on line 16 top: pos.top + "px",

Comment: What do I call the parent div? Does it need an id?

Comment: There is something I don't understand from your answer. I tried this: http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~paradesquare/DPR_Simulator/test_divs.html

Comment: Just post a screen shot of the layout of the forms and ill code it for you. then you can look at the code

Comment: It's simple really. I want the second submit button, the div at the bottom to move up into that second cell
http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~paradesquare/DPR_Simulator/test_divs.html

Comment: Ok i build you the 2 forms, check it. I think This is what you want.https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6Ni6QYT_F-MM0pRY05qcHgwTlk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Perfect: Here it is working: http://www.cegepsherbrooke.qc.ca/~paradesquare/DPR_Simulator/test_divs.html I'll post the definitive code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definitive working answer. I didn't need to create an extra parent DIV and name it id="place_here". Naming a table cell id="place_here" and making it the parent to DIV id="div_2" was enough.
This is a brilliant little work around. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr"><head>
<title>test / crtp</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    position_mdiv()();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        position_mdiv();
    });
})

function position_mdiv(){

    var pos = $('#place_here').position();
    var width = $('#place_here').outerWidth();

    $('#div_2').css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: pos.top +2 + "px",
    left: (pos.left -300 + width) + "px"
});

}

</script>
<body>

<form id="CTRP_Form">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="div_1"><input id="fnam" name="fnam" form="CTRP_Form" type="text"><input type=submit></div>
</td>
<td id="place_here" style="background:yellow;width:300px;padding:0px;border:solid 2px #CCC"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


<div id="div_2"><form id="query_Form"><input id="MyQuery" name="MyQuery" form="query_Form" type="text"><input type=submit></form></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's amazing what jquery and using id="" can do.